# Getting upload progress for Pymongo Gridfs upload into MongoDB database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I'm building an application that allows users to upload video files to a MongoDB database. Currently, I'm using gridfs.put('videoFile') with pymongo to upload to the database. Is there a built-in way to show the user the progress of this upload?

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("")
db = client["db1"]
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db) 
fs.put(myFile) #I need to show the progress of this upload
```

If not, what would be the best way to check the database to see how many chunks have been already uploaded? I could then compare this to the total chunks that need to be uploaded to show the user some kind of progress.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to provide your own IO-like object to https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/gridfs/grid_file.html#gridfs.grid_file.GridIn.write in which you would return the data in chunks and keep track of the size that you returned so far.